# creating menus and forms using <a> tag instead of <form> tag?

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to learn html properly, but i'm still new here. 
My question(s):

1. Is it a good practice to create menus using only `<a>` tags?
2. Is it a good practice to create forms using only `<a>` tags?
3. If yes, why is it bad practice creating them using `<form>` tags?

The reason behind the question is that I did a webpage using `<form>` for both login          forms and menus as well. But I was advised to use only `<a>` tags. I know that it may work     for the main menu, but I find creating functioning login forms with  tag much simpler (since i can use attributes such as action, target, method and so on, and i can use a submit input type. Otherwise I would have to write functions substitute all these functionalities).

I hope you dont find the question stupid, or even worst, duplicated.
Thnx a lot

Comment: Using only tags??????????????? What else would you use??? magic unicorns?

Comment: please put up an example menu

Comment: what i meant is that normally, when you create a form, you start as: <form action="somephpfile.php" method="post/get"> dadadada form content </form>. But I was being suggested to discard the <form> tag. Instead build the whole form with <a> tags. Same thing for the menu. (Though I think he was right about the menu)

Comment: Please supply code. Are you saying you've got a link to (for example) your "about us" page as a form and not an anchor link?

Comment: I can provide with code. But it is something standard. Anyway, here it goes:   <div id="loginform"><form  action="login.php" target="_parent">
   <p>Username</p>
   <input type="text"  placeholder="username" min="8" required="on" autocomplete="off" autofocus="on">
   <p>Password</p>
   <input type="password" placeholder="********" min="10" required="on" autocomplete="off"><br>
   <input type="submit"><br><br>
   <a href="">Forgot your password?</a><br>
   <a href="">Forgot your username and password?</a>
  </form></div>

Comment: Building a form using `a` tags makes no sense whatsoever. Like at all. None. Nada. Nothing.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to format and it seems a mess

Comment: I thought it was useless too initially, but then I thought "im the inexperienced here, maybe the guy is right". That's why I wanted an opinion

Comment: I would suggest first learning basic HTML. At the very least it should help forming a question that actually makes sense.

Comment: Quoting PeeHaa here : "Building a form using a tags makes no sense whatsoever. Like at all. None. Nada. Nothing". My answer: "I thought so. But I am being told otherwise by some guy who knows lots of programming. That's why I needed a third opinion before giving my opinion a shot. And I have gone through the html basic.At least I know what Im saying. If you dont understand it or feel Im not making sense, you dont have to be offensive. Just ignore my question."

Comment: @amygrimaldi If you create a form for the user to input information ie like a login form, then you will need to use the `<form>` tag and specify the actions and method etc of how to deal with the submitted information. Regarding menu's these should be created using `<a>` (anchor tags), you can sit the anchors inside a div etc no problem, but the navigation link to the page itself will be an `<a>`. To use `<form>` to create a navigation menu does not make any sense unless you are trying to do something a bit out of the ordinary. My advice and that is all it is would be to do it this way.

Comment: @amygrimaldi My final point would be to acknowledge that you are correct in saying that if you were to use tags other than `<form>` when creating the form, then you would need to create an onclick function for example that collects the data from each element where a user has interaction. This is definitely a long winded method and more prone to errors by the coder. These functions would also be javascript and if someone turned javascript off, the form would be useless. At the end of it, the form tag is specifically for forms and when you have the right tool for the job, use it. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Menus and forms are completely different things. Menus are used for navigating around a website, while forms are used for sending data from the client to the server.

Generally, you would build a menu with `<a>` tags. It technically can be done using a combination of `<input type="button">` and Javascript, for instance `<input type="button" onclick="window.location.href='newpage.html'" name="Other page">` but there's rarely a situation that calls for that. It's messy, requires significantly more code, and isn't as supported (since users can disable Javascript, or use a browser that doesn't support it).

Forms have to be built using `<form>` and `<input>` tags (there's also `<textarea>`), there's virtually no other option.

For reference, here's an example menu (edit: would need CSS to make it look like a standard menu):

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact us</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

and an example form:

```
<form method="POST" name="login" action="process.php">
    <input type="text" name="user">
    <input type="password" name="pass">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Perhaps that will help clear the two concepts up for you.

Comment: thank you. That was what I thought, but I guess I needed someone to tell me I was not being too stubborn. And I acknowledge that using form tags to create menus was not a good idea.